# python asyncore connectivity

Tags: python, asyncore

is there a way to check connection is established in asyncore?

once asyncore.loop() is called, how can I disconnect the communication between server?

can i just simply call close()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once asyncore.loop() is called, the control is handed over to event loop that runs.

Any code after the asyncore.loop() will be called only after the event loop has been shut down.

Event loop will react to various events and call handlers. **To shutdown the event loop, you must call to stop in one of the event handler where it makes sense.**

For ex: Take a look at the following example.

Code from : http://www.mechanicalcat.net/richard/log/Python/A_simple_asyncore__echo_server__example

```
import asyncore, socket

class Client(asyncore.dispatcher_with_send):
    def __init__(self, host, port, message):
        asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self)
        self.create_socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.connect((host, port))
        self.out_buffer = message

    def handle_close(self):
        self.close()

    def handle_read(self):
        print 'Received', self.recv(1024)
        self.close()

c = Client('', 5007, 'Hello, world')
asyncore.loop()
```

self.close is called inside one of the event handler - handle_read. In this case after the data has been received from the server. it disconnects itself.

References:

- http://effbot.org/librarybook/asyncore.htm
- http://pymotw.com/2/asyncore/index.html#module-asyncore

Comment: How does one set asyncore loop to reconnect after internet died and re-appeared? It just sits as if no new data after lost connection is received and it's still on.

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way to check connection is established in asyncore?

Using with sockets, you can overload **handle_connect()** method of [asyncore.dispatcher](http://docs.python.org/2/library/asyncore.html) to run when socket is connected:

```
import asyncore

class MyClientConnection(asyncore.dispatcher):
    def handle_connect(self):
        '''Socket is connected'''
        print "Connection is established"
```

If you prefer polling, read the variable **connected** in your asyncore.dispatcher:

```
myclient = MyClientConnection()
isConnected = myClient.connected
```